# SQLServer Select Query GROUP BY HAVING across two fields

Tags: sql, sql-server, group-by

This is probably simple, but I'm just not getting it. I'm new to the group by sql query but have a basic understanding of sql selects.

I have a simple table like called Topics:

```
Student | Interviewer | Topic
==========================================
Chuck   | Susan       | Project Management
Jill    | Jack        | Microsoft Word
Chuck   | Jack        | Microsoft Word
Bobby   | Jane        | Project Management
Jill    | Jack        | Python Scripting
```

This is sample data.

For each interview, a row is added for each topic covered. Some students have been interviewed by more than one Interviewer and some interviews only cover one topic and others cover multiple topics.

I am trying to write a query that returns the Student and Interviewer pairs for students that have only been interviewed by a single person but have been asked questions about more than one topic.

So with sample data above, I'd just get back one row: (Jill, Jack).

I've tried various combinations of group by and having sql queries, but none of them are returning what I want. I think I'm missing something when it comes to group by queries. I've read multiple sites about group by and having and have searched through other stack overflow questions, but it's just not clicking.

Comment: sample data and the expected result please.

Comment: @vkp Added the data and result

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do this with `group by` and `having`.

```
select student,max(interviewer) --or min(interviewer) as there will only be one interviewer
from tbl 
group by student
having count(distinct interviewer) = 1 and count(topic) > 1
```

Comment: Thanks! I had missed the "max()" and the "distinct".

Answer (score 0):

I just want to point out that `count(distinct)` could be expensive.  An alternative is:

```
select t.student, max(t.interviewer) 
from tbl t
group by t.student
having min(interviewer) = max(interviewer) and
       min(topic) <> max(topic);
```